# How to create a circumference with CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following markup:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#2"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to make a A tags become circumferences?

I know how to make them circles using `border-radius` ...

But how to make them circumferences?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by circumference here?

Comment: I also have no idea what the hell you mean by `create a circumferences in CSS`. Want to explain? Or maybe look up the word `circumference`?

Comment: A circumference is the outline of the circle ... So I want a circle transparent inside with a, let's say, red border.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean show the circumference like this?

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 5px solid #c00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#1"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#2"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The most confusing point here is the OP also mentioned this *I know how to make them circles using border...*

Comment: I meant border-radius ... I didn't realize that I only needed to add border to it ... Admit it was confusing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with circumference here. But I suppose you can just divide the wanted circumference with 4.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QtE3G/

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 5px solid #aaccdd;
}
```

Here the circumference is 200px.